# Find the quadratic function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image: SkaterBoard]

A skateboard ramp has a horizontal length of $1.5\,\mathrm{m}$ in $0.75\,\mathrm{m}$ height and a curve that can be diagrammed/pictured in a interval of $[1.5\,\mathrm{m} ; 4\,\mathrm{m}]$.

The origin of the coordinate system should be in the left corner of the ramp.

Q: Find the quadratic function.

(Excuse the poor English, not a native English speaker)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: To find the quadratic function for the curve

Comment: As it stands the question is unclear. The dimensions you have given are confusing. Can you provide a picture?

Comment: Next time do not use tinypic , use the image icon here to upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by a quadratic function you mean a parabola with the axis vertical and the vertex at the end of the ramp we can do it.  Taking $x$ horizontal increasing to the left and $y$ vertical increasing up, we know the vertex is at $(1.5,-0.75)$ and that the curve passes through $(0,0)$.  The curve is $y=a(x-1.5)^2-0.75$.  Plugging in $(0,0)$ will give you $a=\frac 14$

Comment: I mean like this type : ax^2+bx+c and the answer that is given for this question is y(x)=0,12x^2+0,96x+1,92

Comment: You can expand what I gave to get that form.  I used different coordinates than your answer key.  I showed the one I used for the vertex, but I don't think it is at all clear what the right coordinate is.  They are also measuring $y$ going downward.  Theirs also does not go through $(0,0)$. You need good data to solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer is $y(x)= 0.12* (x+4)^2 $, so you can correct your question a bit.